# does extjs keep a list of open calls?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I need something to happen after all calls to the server are handled. 
But i don't know in which order these will happen.

So i was wondering if extjs/sencha touch keeps a list of all the open calls somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like this does exist.

```
Ext.Ajax.requests
```

keeps a list of all open calls.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you probably don't need such feature, you could schedule something after n asynchronous functions have returned incrementing a counter when executing each of the calls. On each callback decrement counter, if all have returned, counter will reach zero and you can execute your "global" callback.

Comment: i was thinking about doing it this way, but i wanted to check if extjs didn't do this already by keeping track of all open calls in a global variable.

Comment: Right, let's see if someone comes up with a better answer then :)

Comment: Good to know. Still, I don't know if that would be the best solution for your problem. You would have to do a sort of polling on that to detect the right moment for your callback.

Comment: but if i check if there is still a call open after an asynchronous function returns, i'm doing the same logic as what you suggested but on an implementation of extjs.